# Input validation for correct datatype?

Tags: c++, validation, input, operators, user-input

Here are two loop structures I'm using next to each other to validate integer and character input, one after the other:

```
while (((std::cout << "Enter Strength stat: ") && !(std::cin >> STR)) || ((STR > 20) || (STR < 0)))
{
    std::cout << inval;
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}


while (((std::cout << "Use characters 'Y' or 'N' to confirm. ") && !(std::cin >> confirm_Y_N)) || ((confirm_Y_N != 'Y') && (confirm_Y_N != 'N')))
{
    std::cout << inval;
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

It's been working fine for any sort of non-matching input until my hand slipped and I entered "1-" for the integer value.

This is the output I get when I input anything beginning with the *expected* datatype and then follow it with any other datatype:

```
Enter Strength stat: 1-
Use characters 'Y' or 'N' to confirm. Invalid value! Use characters 'Y' or 'N' to confirm. Y-
Enter Dexterity stat: Invalid value! Enter Dexterity stat:
```

As you can see, it's completely skipping the while loop's conditions for both integer and character input validation one after the other, essentially rendering the program broken.

Why isn't the program discarding the invalid strings as long as the requested character is given at the beginning of it? Shouldn't char only accept single character fields?

Comment: You're doing too much on one line of code.  Break it apart into simple steps, step through with a debugger.

Comment: Note that it has nothing to do with math operators.  The key is your observation about "input anything beginning with the expected datatype and then following it with" but it doesn't matter what you follow it with, as long as it isn't `Y` or `N`.

Comment: Edited my question accordingly. What I still don't understand is why the while loop isn't throwing out the field after it recognizes it's not of char type. My understanding is that char will only be valid so long it is given a single character to hold, what makes it consider the input afterwards?

Comment: When you read, the stream only takes as many characters as can satisfy the current request, and the rest stay in the buffer, to be seen by the *next* read.  There are many cases where this is very desirable, for example if you wanted to accept a distance as "5mi" or "100km".

Answer (score 0):

The unexpected character after the expected data stays in the input buffer.
To fix this you can clear the buffer.

Try inserting

```
std::cin.clear();
fflush(stdin);
```

between the loops. For a more C++-like approach insert

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')
```

This method will ignore any unexpected characters after valid input.

I tested this method and it is working.

Comment: Pay attention to the code in the question that **already calls `clear()` and `ignore()`**

Comment: Yes but the code inside the loop is never executed if the first character is of expected type.

Comment: Hmm, rather than advocating code duplication, perhaps you could explain it in terms of the needed lines not being reached, and suggest a reordering of the loop (possibly with exit condition in the middle) that achieve the desired result?

Comment: That would probably be better. The code has big space for improvemet though and I honestly don't want to take the time and clean it up for the OP.

Comment: That seems fair enough.

Comment: @t0bd1 Can you tell me where my code is lacking? I don't expect you to edit it, I would like to do that myself. If you could just touch on points that aren't proper about my code, I would be grateful.

Comment: @howdoicode Three IMO very important points: 1) Your while-condition is very hard to read and understand. Avoid doing these things all in one line. 2) You should place this code in a function to make reuse easier. Currently you have to copy the whole thing over and over again. If you want to change something it gets complicated. 3) Your naming of variables is inconsistent. All uppercase usually represents constants.